# Logistic linear regression and time series

Tags: time-series, logistic, autocorrelation, trend

Is it safe to run a logistic regression with time as independent variable? For example, I want to test whether a certain outcome (say, blue or red) changes along time.  I know that, in general, one should be careful on time series because of autocorrelation.

EDIT: the dataset I have contains hundreds of observations per months, where there is a decrease in the outcome blue at the advantage of red at the end of the time span. Note that the data might not be completely independent as I have multiple observations for each month coming from the same individual, but the individuals are different for each month (this is not a consequence of poor experimental design, it is impossible to get an observation from the same individual in different months).

Comment: It depends on the aim. If the aim is to model a "growth curve" yes, that's perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! Say that I also want to include multiple predictors like weather condition, geographic area etc. Would it be safe to interpret the coefficients for these predictors and their statistical significance?

Comment: The best way to proceed would depend on the nature of your data. Do you have multiple measurements on the same individuals over time, completely independent measurements of some type, or...? How many observations? Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.